Why am I hearing an electric type of sound from the mic only when AC is on?
Whenever I turn on the A/C, I can hear a sound something electric type on the microphone. It goes away when I turn off the A/C or the A/C compressor stops.
I don't get it; what's causing that, any solutions?
Edit: Forgot to mention, this sound only comes when my mic is plugged in the PC and when I turn on A/C. When mic is plugged in the PC, I can hear that electronic sound. I can listen what mic is recording at the same time by an app, it goes like from silence to that electronic noise after a while when A/C turned on

AC compressors are basically large inductive motors and are prone emitting large electromagnetic fields. Microphones are basically tiny electromagnets that work on the vibration of air, but because they are small metallic parts they also tend to be affected by changing magnetic fields such as the one generated by your AC. The result is a poorly shielded microphone can generally pick up a poorly shielded AC or other motor based device.

So you mean my microphone is the problem, well it is really old so maybe I should get condenser one

How close is the mic to the AC? Have you tried turning it or moving it farther away? Why turn it? Because EM fields are directional -- consider how turning an AM radio can make a station, or make noise, louder.

are you saying that the microphone makes the sound? ... or are you talking about the speakers making the sound?

That sound can be heard from the mic recorded audio, speakers is fine i listen it from my earphone

Ac is 6m away from the pc

I haven't gotten my answer yet, please tell me!
